# If my final destination is Bursa City, Turkey, is landing in istanbul airport my best option?

Tags: turkey

My final destination is bursa city in Turkey. I can have direct flight to Istanbul, from my city alexandria, Egypt but is it best to land in istanbul or should I land in another airport?

I will travel with my 2 kids and wife and I mean by best affordable and comfortable for my wife and kids.

I’m really worried how would I move with at least 3 big luggage and 2 small bags with my two kids. They are almost two years so too heavy to carry and if I used a baby car it would be difficult to move two baby cars and the luggage even with my wife’s help.
So transmitting to ferry from taxi and then another taxi doesn’t seem plausible to me

I do believe that travelling with my family to cairo will be more comfortable and cheaper than travelling long distance in Turkey. But I am not sure if I took off from cairo airport that would allow me to land near Bursa.

There are a lot of international airports in Turkey and i am confused and most online booking websites doesn't allow you to specify generic destination and give you best route.

Thank you for advance.

Comment: Best by what standard? Do you want a domestic flight to Bursa, or are you intending to take a train, or hire a car? Some other criterion?

Comment: This is not answerable without knowing what you mean by "best." Do you mean least time? Lowest cost? Fewest transfers? The answer will also depend upon knowing where you're flying from — there may be no direct flights to Bursa, and you may have to land in Istanbul or somewhere else in any event.  Getting from Istanbul to Bursa will require the same sort of evaluation to decide if you fly, or take the train, or bus from your arrival airport in Turkey to Bursa.

Comment: Thank you @Arthur'sPass and DavidSupportsMonica for your help. I have edited the question.

Comment: Thank you @DavidSupportsMonica I have edited the question. You have helped me with my thought process.

Answer (score 4):

**Sabiha Gokcen (SAW)**

I have never been to the new Istanbul airport, yet I know that it is far from the city centre and commuting from there might be problematic.

Your travel itinerary would look like this:

- Arriving to SAW
- Taking either the city buses (E-11), Havabus or taxi to Kadikoy. If you won't spend time in Istanbul, Havabus is easier because as long as you have cash, you will be alright. You need a card for the city bus. I suspect you can buy the card around, but with the cost of the card itself, you would pay more. Alternatively you can take a taxi. It should cost a little more than 100 TRY, or £11. For two adults, considering the current pandemic, taxi makes more sense.
- Taking IDO ferry from Kadikoy to Bursa. If you can download the Kadikoy map to Google Maps, it would be easier to locate those places.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It’s useful information but it’s hard to move with baggage and Kidd through all those transits.

Comment: I have edited the question please check

Comment: @Abdalla Then taxi. Everything else still holds.

Comment: I am a regular traveller to Turkey (every year since 1998) and I will say 2 things - firstly the infrastructure is excellent. Secondly, turks are very helpful and accomodating to families with kids. If you find it difficult to transfer your bags from a trolley onto the bus, I am sure the bus driver or assistant will jump in to help you.

Comment: @vikingsteve I am Turkish myself and I use SAW 3 to 6 times a year. It is not about helpfulness. The havabus buses operate at full capacity so if you can't have your children sit on your lap, you have to pay for their seat as well. Per seat price should be 14 try, so 4 seats make 56 try. City buses would take 10 try for card deposit plus 7*2=14 try for two adults, which makes 24 try. The taxi is 105-120 try. If I were to come with a family, I would definitely take a taxi. Still, thank you for your kind works about Turkish people :)